# Calculations involving the Ricci tensor on $S^2$.

Tags: differential-geometry, curvature

I am trying to do some calculations with involving the Ricci tensor, but I am off by a factor 2. Here's my problem: The manifold is $S^2$ with the standard metric $g=e^{2\phi}\delta_{ij}$, with $\phi=\ln2-\ln(1+x^2+y^2)$. Using formulas from this wikipedia [page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_formulas_in_Riemannian_geometry) I have $$\Gamma^1_{11}=-\Gamma^1_{22}=\Gamma^2_{12}=\phi_{,1}$$ and $$\Gamma^1_{12}=-\Gamma^2_{11}=\Gamma^2_{22}=\phi_{,2}.$$ If I understand correctly, the Ricci tensor is $$R_{ij}=g_{ij}$$ since the radius of my sphere is 1. I want to calculate $\nabla_m\nabla_iY^m$. Using the Ricci tensor, I would expect
$$
\nabla_m\nabla_iY^m=\nabla_i\nabla_mY^m+R_{im}Y^m =(d(div(Y)))_i+(Y^\flat)_i.
$$

I want to test this formula with a simple vector field
$Y^m=x\delta^m_2-y\delta^m_1$ (with, as usual $x=x^1$ and $y=x^2$). I have
$$
\nabla_iY^j=\frac{x^2+y^2}{1+x^2+y^2}(\delta^2_i\delta^j_1-\delta^1_i\delta^j_2)=A(x,y) (\delta^2_i\delta^j_1-\delta^1_i\delta^j_2).
$$
It follows that $$div(Y)=\nabla_iY^i=0.$$ Also
$$
\nabla_m\nabla_iY^j=A_{,m}(\delta^2_i\delta^j_1-\delta^1_i\delta^j_2)+A(-\Gamma^2_{mi}\delta^j_1+\Gamma^j_{1m}\delta^2_i+\Gamma^1_{mi}\delta^j_2-\Gamma^j_{m2}\delta^1_i)
$$
Contracting
$$
\nabla_m\nabla_iY^i=A(-\Gamma^2_{1m}+\Gamma^2_{1m}+\Gamma^1_{m2}-\Gamma^1_{m2}),
$$
which is to be expected since $div(y)=0$, and
$$
\nabla_m\nabla_iY^m=A_{,1}\delta^2_i-A_{,2}\delta^1_i+A(-\Gamma^2_{i1}+\Gamma^m_{1m}\delta^2_i+\Gamma^1_{2i}-\Gamma^m_{2m}\delta^1_i).
$$
Using the calculated values for the $\Gamma$'s, the above expression simplifies
$$
\nabla_m\nabla_iY^m=-A_{,2}\delta^1_i+A_{,1}\delta^2_i=\frac{1}{2}g_{im}Y^m=\frac{1}{2}(Y^\flat)_i.
$$
which is half of what I would expect based on formula based on the Ricci tensor. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: By standard metric on the unit sphere $S^2$ we usually mean the one coming from the ambient $\mathbb R^3\,.$ This is not what you wrote. The standard metric in Cartesian coordinates it is
\begin{align}
ds^2&=\frac{(1-y^2)\,dx^2+(1-x^2)\,dy^2+2xy\,dx\,dy}{1-x^2-y^2}\,.
\end{align}
So $g_{ij}$ has off-diagonal elements with numerator $xy\,.$ To do calculations it is far easier to go to polar coordinates:
$$
ds^2=d\theta^2+\sin^2\theta\,d\varphi^2\,.
$$
Another weird thing I read in OP is that the Ricci tensor is $R_{ij}=g_{ij}\,.$ Totally wrong. Then I stopped reading.

Comment: Addition: $R_{ij}=g_{ij}$ holds in that special case but not in general.

Answer (score -1):

Too long for another comment.

Your metric can be written as
\begin{align}
g_{11}&=g_{22}=\frac{4}{(1+x^2+y^2)^2}\,, &g_{12}&=g_{21}=0\,.
\end{align}
I verified with a symbolic calculator that in this case
the Ricci tensor $R_{ij}$ is indeed equal to $g_{ij}$
and the  scalar curvature is two like we get on the unit sphere
from the standard metric that I mentioned in a comment.

- So the question arises: What were your coordinates and where does this exercise come from?
- Another remark on your calculation of Christoffel symbols. Do you know the difference between $\Gamma_{ijk}$ and $\Gamma^i_{ij}\,?$ In calculations you start with the former, and in your case
  \begin{align}
  \Gamma_{111} &= -\frac{8x}{1+x^2+y^2}\\
  \end{align}
  which happens to be equal $\frac \partial{\partial x}\phi$ in your special case.
- You expect an identity for the covariant directional derivative $\nabla_m\nabla_iY^m\,.$

Proof.
By the Ricci identity in your link,
$$
\nabla_k\nabla_iY^m-\nabla_i\nabla_kY^m=-R_{ki\ell}{}^mY^\ell
$$
where $R_{ki\ell}{}^m$ is the Riemann tensor which is antisymmetric in $ki\,$. Since the
Ricci tensor is the contracted Riemann tensor
$R_{k\ell}=R_{km\ell}{}^m$ we get
$$
\nabla_m\nabla_iY^m-\nabla_i\nabla_mY^m=R_{i\ell}Y^\ell\,.
$$

Comment: The coordinates are of the stereographic projection on the equatorial plane. I need coordinates that are not singular at the south pole. But I now see the source of my mistake. I left out a factor 2 in the calculation of $\nabla_iY^m$. The correct value is $$\nabla_iY^m=2\frac{x^2+y^2}{1+x^2+y^2}(\delta^2_i\delta^j_1-\delta^1_i\delta^j_2).$$ That is where the factor 2 was missing. All is good now.